# Move files from one directory to another based on file names in csv using macOS Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-big-sur

I am trying to move thousands of files from one directory to another based on the file names that are in a CSV document (one column with just the names).

CSV:

```
filename1
filename2
filename3
```

Folder

```
filenameA
filename1
filename2
filename3
filenameZ
```

NewFolder (after the operation is complete)

```
filename1
filename2
filename3
```

I am trying to do it this way:

```
cat /Users/xxxxx/files.csv | xargs -I {} find /Users/xxxxx/Documents/Folder/ -type f -name "{}*" -exec cp {} /Users/xxxxx/Documents/NewFolder/ \;
```

But it only searches for the last name listed in the csv and ignores all the other names.

Comment: Could you give an example of what's supposed to happen?

Comment: files that are in folder A and whose names are in the csv file get copied over to folder B. Files whose names are not in the CSV stay in folder A.

Comment: That's trivial in a simple scripting language such as Ruby. Is there some really good reason why this needs to be a bash one liner?

Comment: thanks @matt, it does not have to be a bash one liner. this is just how I thought I could do it. open to any other suggestions!

Comment: So do you know a scripting language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your terminal window, you can use this command to move files listed in CSV from Folder to NewFolder:

`for file in $(cat CSV); do mv Folder/$file NewFolder; done`

Comment: and replace `mv` with `cp` if you only want to copy and not move the files.  They are different operations, and you refer to both in your question and comments.