# Move files to different directory based on subset of string matching in filenames in csv file

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have files as follows in a folder :

```
Peter_XY.tgz Tom_GF.tgz Harry_AB.tgz
```

which I am trying to put in different folders based on two txt files that look as follows :

```
A.txt 
AB1
AB
XY
SE
12S
G78

B.txt

OR1
IU345
PIE678
GF
BF
MIL
```

I am trying to put the files in two different folders :

```
A 
Peter_XY.tgz Harry_AB.tgz

B
Tom_GF.tgz
```

Now, based on the code suggested here: [Move files from one directory to another based on file names in csv using macOS Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73030342/move-files-from-one-directory-to-another-based-on-file-names-in-csv-using-macos)

I tweaked the code as follows :

```
for file in $(cat A.txt); do mv $file A; done
for file in $(cat B.txt); do mv $file B; done
```

How to make sure the code just reads after the '_' sign ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script will look for all files with name ending in `.txt` the variable `txtFile` in the outer for loop, so `A.txt` and `B.txt` will be separate loops thru the outer loop.

The inner for loop uses the code you provided to get the charaters after `_` but before `.tgz`. The variable is `seek`.

The `basename` w/ extension `.txt` of variable `txtFile` is used as the destination directory. The variable `DEST`, so `A.txt` becomes `A`.

Finally, any found file matching filename from one of the text files is moved into the destination directory. In other words, `mv` (move) `*_${seek}.tgz` (any file ending in `_` `seek` `.tgz`) to `$DEST`.

```bash
for txtFile in *.txt ; do
   DEST=$(basename $txtFile .txt);
   echo "processing $txtFile by moving matches to $DEST";
   for seek in $(cat $txtFile) ; do
     echo "Moving files matching *_${seek}.tgz to $DEST";
     mv *_${seek}.tgz $DEST;
   done;
done
```

Here is output given the files you specified above:

```
processing A.txt by moving matches to A
Moving files matching *_AB1.tgz to A
mv: rename *_AB1.tgz to A/*_AB1.tgz: No such file or directory
Moving files matching *_AB.tgz to A
Moving files matching *_XY.tgz to A
Moving files matching *_SE.tgz to A
mv: rename *_SE.tgz to A/*_SE.tgz: No such file or directory
Moving files matching *_12S.tgz to A
mv: rename *_12S.tgz to A/*_12S.tgz: No such file or directory
Moving files matching *_G78.tgz to A
mv: rename *_G78.tgz to A/*_G78.tgz: No such file or directory
processing B.txt by moving matches to B
Moving files matching *_OR1.tgz to B
mv: rename *_OR1.tgz to B/*_OR1.tgz: No such file or directory
Moving files matching *_IU345.tgz to B
mv: rename *_IU345.tgz to B/*_IU345.tgz: No such file or directory
Moving files matching *_PIE678.tgz to B
mv: rename *_PIE678.tgz to B/*_PIE678.tgz: No such file or directory
Moving files matching *_GF.tgz to B
Moving files matching *_BF.tgz to B
mv: rename *_BF.tgz to B/*_BF.tgz: No such file or directory
Moving files matching *_MIL.tgz to B
mv: rename *_MIL.tgz to B/*_MIL.tgz: No such file or directory
```

And the results are like this:

```
├── A
│   ├── Harry_AB.tgz
│   └── Peter_XY.tgz
├── A.txt
├── B
│   └── Tom_GF.tgz
├── B.txt
```